# How to find the error in the following code to generate categories automatically for a CPT using WordPress

Tags: wordpress

This following code should create child categories for child posts and allow updating posts to change the category accordingly. The category structure will mirror the hierarchical structure of the posts. Additionally, it will delete categories that don’t have a corresponding post, but it is not working 100%, it is creating all categories as parent, and not their children, as intended…

```
// Add a custom function to generate hierarchical categories
function generate_hierarchical_categories() {
    // Query all posts within the "Operations" custom post type
    $all_posts_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type'      => 'operations',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // Retrieve all posts
    ));

    // Create an array to store the categories
    $categories = array();

    // Loop through all the posts
    while ($all_posts_query->have_posts()) {
        $all_posts_query->the_post();

        // Get the post ID and parent ID
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        $post_parent_id = wp_get_post_parent_id($post_id);

        // Get the post title
        $post_title = get_the_title();

        // Create the category slug and name
        $category_slug = sanitize_title($post_title);
        $category_name = $post_title;

        // Create the category object
        $category = (object) array(
            'id'     => $post_id,
            'parent' => $post_parent_id,
            'slug'   => $category_slug,
            'name'   => $category_name,
        );

        // Store the category in the array
        $categories[$post_id] = $category;
    }

    // Reset the post data
    wp_reset_postdata();

    // Loop through the categories and generate the hierarchical structure
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        // Check if the category already exists
        $existing_category = get_term_by('slug', $category->slug, 'operations-category');

        // If the category doesn't exist, create it
        if (!$existing_category) {
            $category_args = array(
                'description' => '',
                'slug'        => $category->slug,
            );

            // If the post is a child, set the parent category
            if ($category->parent) {
                // Get the parent category
                $parent_category = $categories[$category->parent];

                // If the parent category exists, set it as the parent
                if ($parent_category) {
                    // Check if the parent category already exists
                    $existing_parent_category = get_term_by('slug', $parent_category->slug, 'operations-category');

                    if ($existing_parent_category) {
                        $category_args['parent'] = $existing_parent_category->term_id;
                    } else {
                        // Create the parent category first
                        $parent_category_args = array(
                            'description' => '',
                            'slug'        => $parent_category->slug,
                        );

                        $parent_category_id = wp_insert_term($parent_category->name, 'operations-category', $parent_category_args);

                        if (!is_wp_error($parent_category_id)) {
                            $category_args['parent'] = $parent_category_id['term_id'];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // Insert the category and get its ID
            $category_id = wp_insert_term($category->name, 'operations-category', $category_args);

            // If the category was created successfully, update its parent category and slug if it's a child category
            if (!is_wp_error($category_id)) {
                // If the post is a child, set the parent category for the child category
                if ($category->parent) {
                    $parent_term_id = isset($category_args['parent']) ? $category_args['parent'] : 0;
                    $parent_term = get_term($parent_term_id, 'operations-category');
                    $parent_term_slug = $parent_term->slug;

                    $child_term_slug = $category->slug;
                    $child_term_parent = $parent_term_slug . '/' . $child_term_slug;

                    wp_update_term($category_id['term_id'], 'operations-category', array('parent' => $parent_term_id, 'slug' => $child_term_parent));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Delete categories that do not have a corresponding post
    $existing_categories = get_terms(array(
        'taxonomy'   => 'operations-category',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ));

    foreach ($existing_categories as $existing_category) {
        $existing_category_slug = $existing_category->slug;

        // Check if the category exists in the generated categories array
        $matching_category = array_filter($categories, function ($category) use ($existing_category_slug) {
            return $category->slug === $existing_category_slug;
        });

        // If there is no matching category, delete the category
        if (empty($matching_category)) {
            wp_delete_term($existing_category->term_id, 'operations-category');
        }
    }
}

// Hook the custom function to the 'init' action
add_action('init', 'generate_hierarchical_categories');

// Hook the custom function to the 'save_post' action to update categories when a post is edited
add_action('save_post', 'generate_hierarchical_categories');

// Add a custom function to update categories when a post is edited
function update_post_categories($post_id) {
    // Get the post object
    $post = get_post($post_id);

    // Check if the post is of the "Operations" custom post type
    if ($post->post_type === 'operations') {
        // Get the parent ID of the post
        $post_parent_id = wp_get_post_parent_id($post_id);

        // Get the category slug and name for the post
        $category_slug = sanitize_title($post->post_title);
        $category_name = $post->post_title;

        // Update the category for the post
        wp_update_term($post_id, 'operations-category', array(
            'name' => $category_name,
            'slug' => $category_slug,
        ));

        // If the post is a child, update the parent category for the child category
        if ($post_parent_id) {
            // Get the parent category
            $parent_category = get_term_by('slug', $category_slug, 'operations-category');

            // If the parent category exists, update the parent for the child category
            if ($parent_category) {
                $parent_category_id = $parent_category->term_id;
                wp_update_term($post_id, 'operations-category', array('parent' => $parent_category_id));
            }
        }
    }
}

// Hook the custom function to the 'save_post' action to update categories when a post is edited
add_action('save_post', 'update_post_categories');
```

I want to make this to work in WordPress using a custom post type.